# What do people mean with a vev=diag( -2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,3,3,3,3)?

Tags: group-theory, higgs, beyond-the-standard-model

For example, in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1507.06712) on page 21 the authors write the vev that breaks $SO(10)$ to $SU(4)\times SU(2) \times SU(2)$

$$ <54>= 1/5 \cdot diag( -2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,3,3,3,3) \omega_s$$

where $\omega_s$ denotes the scale.

***What do the authors mean by this?***

The Higgs field or Higgs fields that develop a vev are elements of the $54$ representation of $SO(10)$. Because $10 \otimes 10 = 1_s \oplus 54_s \oplus45_a$, we can write each element of $54$ as a $10 \times 10$ matrix.

This is similar how one determines the particle content of the $10$ representation of $SU(5)$, written as $5 \times 5$ matrix, by using $5 \otimes 5 =10 \oplus \ldots$.

The quantum numbers of the 10 inedpendent fields $\in$ 10 are given by

$$ QN(10_{ij})= QN(5_i) + QN(5_j) ,$$
where $10_{ij}$ denotes the $ij$ element of the $5 \times 5$ matrix.

This yields

[image]

Completely equivalently we can determine the quantum numbers of the Higgs fields in the $54$ representation of $S0(10)$ and write them in a $10 \times 10$ matrix.

**How does $ <54>= 1/5 \cdot diag( -2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,3,3,3,3) \omega_s$ tell me which of these $54$ Higgs fields gets a vev?**

Comment: The expression you write gives a traceless symmetric $10 \times 10$ matrix, which hence sits in the $54$ of $SO(10)$.

Comment: @Olof yes I agree with you... But then what does the vev= diag(... mean?

Comment: it means that the vacuum expectation value is chosen to be proportional to that particular diagonal matrix

Comment: @Olof Yes, again I agree, but my problem remains. For concreteness let's consider a simplified setup. A computation similar to $QN(10_{ij})= QN(5_i) + QN(5_j) ,$ which yields for example the 10 of $SU(5)$ as quoted in the OP, yields a matrix for the Higgs bosons. For example, in a $2 \times 2$ case: $ \begin{pmatrix} A & B  \\ C& D  \end{pmatrix} $, where $A,B,C,D$ denote four different Higgs fields. Now given a vev = $diag(1,-1)w$, does this mean the Higgs field $A$ gets a vev $w$ and the Higgs field $D$ gets a vev $-w$?.