# Given a VEV how can I compute which generators remain unbroken using tensor methods?

Tags: group-theory, lie-algebra, symmetry-breaking, beyond-the-standard-model

This is a follow up to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/192274/how-to-find-the-remaining-subgroup-after-some-higgs-field-gets-a-vev).

A generator $T_a$ of a given gauge group $G$ remains unbroken after some Higgs field $\Phi$ gets a vev if

$$ T_a \langle\Phi\rangle =0 $$

I'm trying to understand how I can check this explicitly using matrices for the vev and the generators in different representations (i.e. non-adjoint Higgs).

Let's assume we have Higgs fields in some representation $R$, of a gauge group $G$ as for example $SO(10)$, that can be written as a matrix. Then given a vev written as a matrix how can I compute which generators remain unbroken after the Higgs fields get a vev?

For concreteness, let's consider the $SO(10)$ example. The gauge bosons live in the adjoint 45-dim rep. Because $10 \otimes 10= (1 \oplus 54)_S \oplus 45$, we can write each gauge boson as a (antisymmetric) $10 \times 10$ matrix $M_{45}$. Further let's assume we have Higgs fields in the $54$ dimensional representation. For the same reason we can write these 54 Higgs fields as (symmetric) $10 \times 10 $ matrices $M_{54}$.

Then how can I compute which generators remain unbroken when some of the Higgs fields (or just one) gets a vev? (The vev is then a $10 \times 10 $ matrices $M_{54VEV}$)

**Three possibilities that come to my mind:**

- $M_{45}M_{54VEV}=0$
- $M_{45}M_{54VEV}M_{45}^T=0$
- $[M_{45},M_{54VEV}]=0$

*Which one is correct or is it something completely different?*

EDIT: Related MathStackexchange questions:

- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1383093/transformation-law-for-symmetric-rank-2-tensors

Comment: The vev should be a column vector $|\Phi\rangle_{VEV}$, no?

Comment: No, see for example this question http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/196988/ or the paper quoted there. In addition a vev in matrix form is what one usually uses to break $SU(5)$ to the standard model gauge group.

Comment: But you are not in the adoint, you are in the defining of SO(10), so $\Phi$ is a column vector.